# crypt() on different machines

Tags: debian, password, mysql

Because of a hardware issue i need to [migrate many virtual users](https://serverfault.com/questions/259523/migrate-live-server) to a new machine. Their passwords stored in MySQL encrypted with [`ENCRYPT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_encrypt) which using `crypt()`eventually.

Maybe it's my fault but `salt` wasn't added when passwords were stored so they're totally random. My basic idea was to dump the database then import it. When i tried to store the same string in the same machine with `ENCRYPT` it gave me different results. Will users' passwords work on the new machine?

Update on environment and encrypting method:

- The old machine is running Debian Etch with MySQL 5.0
- New machine will run Debian Squeeze with MySQL 5.1
- The encrypting method is MySQL's default `ENCRYPT`
- Salt wasn't added originally
- I don't know the passwords

Thank you for your feedback, fabrik

Comment: If you're migrating to a different operating system (the hardware is irrelevant), it's possible (but rare) that they might use different algorithms to encrypt passwords. If you want reassurance on that, you need to say exactly what the old and new OS are, and possibly how MySQL was configured (I don't know where or even if MySQL can be configured to use a non-default algorithm, e.g. MD5 or Blowfish or SHA-256).

Comment: @Gilles thank you for your comment, see my update on my question.

Comment: If you're upgrading to a more recent version of the same OS, you have nothing to worry about. Making previously-existing passwords unusable would be a huge incompatibility!

Comment: @Gilles i hope you're right :)

Answer (score 8):

From the provided link to `ENCRYPT()`

> If no salt argument is given, a random
>   value is used.

`salt` is a 2 character string, saved in the beginning of the encrypted text. e.g. encrypting a string with salt='df', 'df' is in the start of the output product.

```
mysql> SELECT ENCRYPT('hello','df');
+-----------------------+
| ENCRYPT('hello','df') |
+-----------------------+
| dfbVa429UeC0U         | 
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Another example, no `salt`

```
mysql> SELECT ENCRYPT('hello');
+------------------+
| ENCRYPT('hello') |
+------------------+
| oBSydDfeNx5ug    | 
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now use the first two characters of the previous string as `salt`

```
mysql> SELECT ENCRYPT('hello','oB');
+-----------------------+
| ENCRYPT('hello','oB') |
+-----------------------+
| oBSydDfeNx5ug         | 
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Same output.

You most probably won't have a problem, but just to be 100% sure (that crypt implementation is the same), create a test account on the old machine and migrate it to the new one. Check if the password works for both of them.

EDIT:

`salt` is **ALWAYS** stored in the first letters of the password's encrypted string. There is **NO WAY** `salt` is lost, without `salt` users wouldn't be able to login in your old machine in the first place. You do not need to (and you shouldn't) know any passwords.

If you're migrating from etch to squeeze, the most sensible way to go, is to setup a testing server with Debian Squeeze. You do not need hardware to do that, setup a VirtualBox guest for example. Then create a new user in your old machine and migrate his account to the testing machine. If the password works for both machines, then you 're good to go, it's the only way to be 99.9% sure. Testing migrations is a must anyway, you should worry about a lot more problems appearing in them.

Comment: @forcefsck at first sight i thought this what i'm looking for. Unfortunately i know nothing about what is `hello` and that's my problem. I don't want to decrypt these encrypted strings but i'd like to be sure about my newly imported database will accept original passwords.

Comment: @fabrik: how come you write English and know nothing about `'hello'`? ;)  Well, `hello` is just hello here--a test string to demonstrate the `ENCRYPT` behavior.

Comment: @alex I'm glad you're so funny but the original problem for me is not too funny. And i hope you're just kidding about hello.

Comment: @fabrik, I'm not decrypting anything, I'm just showing how the password checking mechanism is able to match two encrypted strings of the same password by extracting `salt` from the already stored value. Which is why the system works where it is currently.

Comment: @forcefsck oops maybe i was really equivocal. I totally understood your example but i think it won't solve my problem, because i know nothing about users' passwords to write a script then insert passwords into the new database as you wrote.

Comment: @fabrik, I'm not telling you to re-encode the passwords, my point is that if you migrate the database and use the same software, it will still work, because `salt` is not really lost.

Comment: @forcefsck The two machine will be different (architecture, OS, MySQL), salt originally wasn't added, all i have now is a table with unknown encrypted passwords. I'd like to be sure about they will work on the new box, but looks like until the server isn't up and running i can't get the answer. :( The worst case will be if i need to regenerate new passwords which won't make our customers happy. This what i want to avoid.

Comment: @fabrik, ENCRYPT() created a random `salt` for each password and saved it inside the encoded string which is what you have in your _table with unknown encrypted passwords_. This is why your users are able to login in your current system now. You will only have a problem if the implementation of crypt() in your new system, creates different strings with the same `salt`, which I doubt.

Comment: Can't you afford setting up a staging system with software identical to the new machine and test if it works as expected?  Or just don't switch to new machine util it was actually tested.

Comment: @alex: Let me reformulate the main points of forcefsck's correct answer. ENCRYPT always uses salt. You can pass an explicit salt, but that's rare; when storing passwords, you must use a random salt. The salt is stored in plain text together with the result of encrypting the salt+password.

Comment: @Gilles: thanks, that was clear to me already.  I've just tried to push OP into doing something sensible about his problem instead of theorizing here how it might not work.

Comment: @alex: Oops, I replied to the wrong comment.